# unable to find valid certification path to requested target PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, spring, security

I have create a custom keystore file xyz.jsk, When I tried to using this file I am getting exception

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for : sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

```
   String keyStorePassword = "NEWPASSWORD";
     KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
     ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    //  File file = new 
   File(classLoader.getResource(keyStoreFile).getFile());

     File file = new File(dir, "xyz.jks");;


    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), 
    keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                    .build(),
            NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);

    ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory())
            .setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(strTimeOut));
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(urlPath, HttpMethod.POST, entity, clazz);
```

Answer (score 2):

Programmatic solution for certificate solution
Please look into following imports :-

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
```

Now the function

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = getClientConfig();

TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return null;
}

public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
}
} };
SSLContext sc = null;
try {
    sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // do nothing
    }

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(clientConfig).sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier((s1, s2) -> true)
    .build();
```